# Row Count Zero in Hive Metastore for table ingested using Sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop, hive-metastore

Row count is coming as zero in hive metastore for the table which we are ingesting from DB2 or Oracle to Hive.

... numRows property has 0 value ...

Please note: Count in table is coming correctly but issue is only when we are fetching the values from metastore. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Run analyze command:

```
ANALYZE TABLE db_name.tablename COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  [FOR COLUMNS]
```

[See more details here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work but taking quite good amount of time for big partitioned tables.

Comment: If a table gets refreshed in hive on daily basis using Sqoop only, than do we need to run this command for that particular table on daily basis in order to get updated values in hive metastore or it is a one time activity and next time when sqoop gets latest data to hive, values in hive metastore gets updated automatically.

Comment: @Nitish Do analyze only updated partitions, not the whole table, just after sqoop run. Partitions which were not loaded during last sqoop run will have metadata unchanged

Comment: Is there any better way of doing this. The above solution works correctly but for non partitioned tables which are getting ingested on daily basis using Sqoop it is taking quite long time to analyse the statistics. This will result in increase in overall ingestion time of a job significantly.

Comment: @Nitish Unfortunately I do not know the way how to make sqoop gather stats during import. For hive it is possible to auto-gather stats during insert.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.